# svg programming, coords are messed up

Tags: php, svg, inkscape

I'd like to make an svg with lines:

```
M 0,0 0,110 90,50 90,-40 z
```

so that I can move the points with JavaScript or PHP.

My question is that how can I make sense which number is which?
I tried this with inkscape and it seems to remove the L from every coordinate
and also the last is somehow -40 even though the whole item should be above the 0,0 point.

How is the coordinates suddenly inverted?

I understood that M is to set absolute point, and L should also draw line to absolute coords but it's not.

```
d="M 0,0 L 0,110 L 90,50 L 90,120 z"
```

Comment: add some code please to manipulate your problem

Answer (score 2):

L is implicit i.e. The first two numbers after an M are a move but [all subsequent pairs are then interpreted as L commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands).

> If a moveto is followed by multiple pairs of coordinates, the subsequent pairs are treated as implicit lineto commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this was indeed so. 
Inkscape has inverted Y-axis and this makes it hard to use working with svg source.